# JavaScript beginner: why does this not work?

Tags: javascript, html

My html page is not responding to this code I wrote in JS, i'm a total beginner, and just started learning JS, can somebody tell me why this doesn't work?

```js
/* this is a practice file that'll play with js
nothing strange to look at here folks! */

var firstName = 'Steven';
var lastName = 'Curry';
var fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;

function Hotel(HotelName){
 this.HotelName = HotelName;
 this.numRooms = 20;
 this.numGuests;
 this.checkAvailability {
  if(numRooms != 20 ){
   return true;
  }
  else{
   return false;
  }
 }
 this.getHotelName = function(){
  //can it work with this dot operator?
  return this.HotelName;
 }
}

var HiltonHotel = new Hotel('Hilton');
var hName = document.getElementById('hotelName');
hName.textContent = getHotelName();

var el = document.getElementById('name');
el.textContent = fullName;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div id = 'greeting'> Hello
  <span id="name">friend</span>!
  <h1>Welcome To the <span id = 'hotelName'>Hyatt</span>
 </div>
 <script 
 src = "https://stacksnippets.net/js">
 </script>
</body>
</html
```

I'm pretty sure it's ordering and my syntax i need to work on, any advice is greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: `this.checkAvailability {` isn’t valid syntax. You should probably start with simpler stuff.

Comment: You have to access the property from the instance! `HiltonHotel.getHotelName()` etc. Also your `checkAvailability` method (which has invalid syntax) makes no sense. If there are 20 rooms, then it's still available... please check the console for errors before asking here

Comment: In the future, please be specific. *"Does not work"* doesn't tell us much. Do you get an error and, if so, on what line and what does the error say? Does anything happen?

Comment: Thanks for the advice i'll make sure to be more clear next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few misunderstandings:

- `checkAvailability` is a function, you are missing parens.
- while accessing the `getHotelName` function, you have to refer to the `HiltonHotel` variable, to be able to access and call that function.
- few minor errors in your `html` code, while operating in *code snippet*, you don't have to add a separate script, it's connected together by default.

```js
var firstName = 'Steven';
var lastName = 'Curry';
var fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;

function Hotel(HotelName) {
  this.HotelName = HotelName;
  this.numRooms = 20;
  this.numGuests;
  this.checkAvailability = function() { // it's a function (missing parens)
    if (numRooms != 20) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  this.getHotelName = function() {
    return this.HotelName;
  }
}

var WeiHotel = new Hotel('Hilton');
var hName = document.getElementById('hotelName');
hName.textContent = WeiHotel.getHotelName(); // refer to the `WeiHotel` variable

var el = document.getElementById('name');
el.textContent = fullName;
```

```html
<div id='greeting'> Hello
  <span id="name">friend</span>!
  <h1>Welcome To the <span id='hotelName'>Hyatt</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

An extension to the answer of @KindUser:

You're not using closures anywhere in this class to store some private state. Therefore you should attach the methods to the prototype and not to the instance itself. It's more economic, because now all instances share one function, not one per instance. And the JS engine can optimize that better.

Then, you have another error in `checkAvailability`: `numRooms` needs to be addressed as `this.numRooms` because it is a property of `this` instance, and there is no variable with this name.

And one about style. If you have something like

```
if(condition){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

you can simplify this to:

```
return condition;

//or if you want to enforce a Boolean value, 
//but your condition may return only a truthy/falsy value:
return Boolean(condition);
//sometimes also written as:
return !!(condition);
```

Next. Stick to the coding standards. In JS a variable/property starting with an uppercase letter would indicate a class/constructor, therefore `HotelName`, `HiltonHotel`, `WeiHotel` are misleading.
And I find the property name `hotelName` redundant and counter-intuitive. Imo you have a `Hotel`, it has a `name`, but that's just an opinion.

```js
var firstName = 'Steven';
var lastName = 'Curry';
var fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;

function Hotel(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.numRooms = 20;
  this.numGuests;
}
Hotel.prototype.checkAvailability = function() {
  return this.numRooms !== 20;
}
Hotel.prototype.getHotelName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

var hotel = new Hotel('Hilton');
var hName = document.getElementById('hotelName');
hName.textContent = hotel.getHotelName(); // refer to the `weiHotel` variable

var el = document.getElementById('name');
el.textContent = fullName;
```

```html
<div id='greeting'> Hello
  <span id="name">friend</span>!
  <h1>Welcome To the <span id='hotelName'>Hyatt</span></h1>
</div>
```

or as an ES6 class *(and some playin around)*:

```js
class Person{
  constructor(firstName, lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  //this is a getter, you can read it like a property
  get fullName(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
  //this function is implicitely called whenever you try to convert 
  //an instance of `Person` into a string.
  toString(){
    return this.fullName;
  }
}

class Hotel{
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numRooms = 20;
    this.numGuests;
  }
  checkAvailability() {
    return this.numRooms !== 20;
  }
  getHotelName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

var steve = new Person('Steven', 'Curry');
var hotel = new Hotel('Hilton');

var hName = document.getElementById('hotelName');
hName.textContent = hotel.getHotelName(); // refer to the `weiHotel` variable

var el = document.getElementById('name');
el.textContent = steve.fullName;

//this uses the `toString()` method to convert the `Person` steve into a string
//for people, this makes sense, for the Hotel you'd want to think:
//  - where do I want to use this?
//  - and what should this string contain?
console.log("Hello, I'm " + steve + " and I'm at the "+ hotel.name);
```

```html
<div id='greeting'> Hello
  <span id="name">friend</span>!
  <h1>Welcome To the <span id='hotelName'>Hyatt</span></h1>
</div>
```